# Lua C API - Getting metatable from a table on stack

Tags: c++, lua, metatable

Let's say we have a table that was passed to a function and it's now on top of the stack like so:

```
// -1 = table
```

Is it possible to get the metatable from that table on stack? I can simply get it with a known-name identifier like so:

```
luaL_getmetatable(L, "Foo");
```

But I want to re-use the function and get the metatable from the table that's in the stack.

There is probably an easy way to do this, but I can't seem to find a function for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `lua_getmetatable` rather than `luaL_getmetatable`. The `lua_` version is equivalent to `getmetatable()` in Lua, i.e. it gets the metatable from a value on the stack. The `luaL_` version is for looking up (by name) metatables registered earlier with `luaL_newmetatable`.

In your case, it would just be:

```
// push the table
lua_getmetatable(L, -1);
// table is still on the stack at -2
// its metatable on top of it at -1
```

Note that `lua_getmetatable()` returns 1 and pushes the metatable if the value has one, and returns 0 and pushes *nothing* if it doesn't have a metatable - rather than pushing nil as, for example, `lua_getglobal` does.